# How to run a Zeos filter code for multiple TZquery?

Tags: delphi, zeos

I used to use a single code for my filter queries,  and tried it using multiple TZquery but it won't work. All the tables contain the client_id column, and I wanted for the code to search for the infos with the client id on the TEdit, it works for a single TZquery, but not for more than one. Thanks.

Here is the code I used:

```
zquery1.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive]; 
zquery1.Filtered := Length(Edit1.Text) > 0; 
if zquery1.Filtered then 
  zquery1.Filter := 'client_id like ' + 
       QuotedStr('' + Edit1.Text + '') // Zeos- Syntax 
else 
  zquery1.Filter := '';

zquery2.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive]; 
zquery2.Filtered := Length(Edit1.Text) > 0; 
if zquery2.Filtered then 
  zquery2.Filter := 'client_id like ' + QuotedStr('' + Edit1.Text + '') // Zeos- Syntax 
else 
  zquery2.Filter := '';

zquery3.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive]; 
zquery3.Filtered := Length(Edit1.Text) > 0; 
if zquery3.Filtered then 
  zquery3.Filter := 'client_id like ' + QuotedStr('' + Edit1.Text + '') // Zeos- Syntax 
else 
  zquery3.Filter := '';

zquery4.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive]; 
zquery4.Filtered := Length(Edit1.Text) > 0; 
if zquery4.Filtered then 
  zquery4.Filter := 'client_id like ' + QuotedStr('' + Edit1.Text + '') // Zeos- Syntax 
else 
  zquery4.Filter := '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only change a filter condition when filtered is false.  So I would write your code as follows

```
zquery1.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive]; 
zquery1.Filtered := false;
if Length(Edit1.Text) > 0 then
begin
  zquery1.Filter := 'client_id like ' +  QuotedStr(trim(Edit1.Text)) ;
  zquery1.Filtered := true;
end;

zquery2.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive]; 
zquery2.Filtered := false;
if Length(Edit1.Text) > 0 then
begin
  zquery2.Filter := 'client_id like ' + QuotedStr('' + Edit1.Text + '') // Zeos- Syntax 
  zquery2.Filtered := true;
end;

zquery3.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive]; 
zquery3.Filtered := false;
if Length(Edit1.Text) > 0 then
begin
  zquery3.Filter := 'client_id like ' + QuotedStr('' + Edit1.Text + '') // Zeos- Syntax 
  zquery3.Filtered := true;
end;

zquery3.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive]; 
zquery3.Filtered := false;
if Length(Edit1.Text) > 0 then
begin
  zquery3.Filter := 'client_id like ' + QuotedStr('' + Edit1.Text + '') // Zeos- Syntax 
  zquery3.Filtered := true;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the late response, was out the past days. :D